# How to get width and height of particular table data(td) in dynamic table

Tags: angular, styles, dynamic-data

I have a two different components like A and B. A have some dynamic data table values. And also B table need to show B's table data along with A's table some values too. The components have no relationship. Data fetching part is working fine for us.

The problem is, if A's data having more than two lines means we get a allingment issue for B's table

Can anyone help me to find A's table data height and width. Then we solve the issue.

Comment: Hi, can you update your question with an image that I can see what is your actual problem? Or you can share a sample problem in stackblitz too. :)

Comment: @Monisha Are you fetch `offsetWidth` in `ngAfterViewInit`?

Comment: @Arunkumar Ramasamy I didn't get values. Its shows undefined

Comment: @Monisha can you share a sample in https://stackblitz.com

Answer (score 0):

have you tried bootstrap's flex layout?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col">
        <table border="1"> <!-- Table 1 -->
          <tr>
             <th>Company</th>
             <th>Contact</th>
             <th>Country</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
             <td>Maria Anders</td>
             <td>Germany</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
             <td>Maria Anders</td>
             <td>Germany</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
             <td>Maria Anders</td>
             <td>Germany</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
     </div>
     <div class="col d-flex align-items-start">
        <table border="1"> <!-- Table 2 -->
          <tr>
             <th>Company</th>
             <th>Contact</th>
             <th>Country</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
             <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
             <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, table 2 will keep its align at the top of its container no matter how long table 1 contents may be.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Actually we used angular material table. We tried to get height and width using @viewChild and Element Ref (e1.nativeElement.offsetWidth). But that also not working

Answer (score 0):

Try below methods:
1.add style="overflow-x:auto;" to div tag which contains table

2.or use bootstrap class '.table-responsive'

these two will help you in making the table responsive

Comment: If I tried this method, its affect whole table right. I need to set if data more than 3 lines not for all. And also we implemented using angular material for data table

Answer (score 0):

Since Table A's content as you mentioned above is dynamic. You can only get its updated dimensions (height and width) in the next clock tick. In this case, you can use a setTimeout to have some delay in getting its updated dimensions. Try below code snippet.

```
private getUpdatedDimensions() {
   setTimeout(
     _ => {
        const containerW = this.tableContainer.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
        const containerH = this.tableContainer.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
        console.log(`Width: ${containerw},  H: ${containerH}`);
     }, 0
   );
}
```

Comment: A and B both table are dynamic only

Comment: You can try the above code and let me know if it helps.

Comment: You have to call the above function only after the table is updated.